# Translation of ～てどうか

Tags: translation, spoken-language, academic-japanese

I recently had a major error on my translation for an agency, and am still confused.

The wider context is that this person doesn't like dealing (being seen) by staff when borrowing money, so prefers to use automated services.  This is his final thought:

> **だから人に見られてどうか**、**っていうので**、機械にするか、生身の人間のやりとりがいいかっていう、使い分けかなとは思ってます。

I translated it as:

> "So, regardless of whether I'm seen by other people..."

But apparently that's incorrect.

Also, with regards to incorporating っていうので, could it be something like:

> "So, **as I say**,..."

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `"いう = to say"` is such a dangerous delusion and unfortunately, it is all too common.

Answer (score 3):

To rephrase it in a bit simpler (or, a bit less colloquial) way...

だから、人に見られてどう感じるか（i.e. 見られたら嫌か、平気か）、ということで（≂ ということを基準にして）、機械にするか生身の人間とのやりとりにするかを決めている（≂ ～かの使い分けをしている）と思います。

which is roughly saying...

"So, I think I/you/people decide whether I/you/they should use 機械(=ATM) or 人間(=窓口), depending on how I/you/they would feel (= whether I/you/they like it or not) if I/you/they were seen (borrowing money) by others."

Answer (score 1):

What he says "だから人に見られてどうか、っていうので" is vague, at least to me. I simply can't conclude if he does not want to show his bankbook or some other reason.

"どうか、っていうので" is also not a natural phrase. So, it might be showing his unwillingness for the transaction in person to person since, as you say, at least he does not like his transaction in person to person.

So, My attempt translation what he said is  "I am ambivalent about someone seeing my transaction, so which one to deal with machine or person is it depends."